# How to get the row content of an Apexgrid in VB6 using Testcomplete?

Tags: vb6, testcomplete

We are using **TestComplete** to automate a desktop application written in **VB6**.

We are stuck in getting the row content of an Apex grid with WndClass **TG60.ApexGirdOleDB32.20**.

There is [some information in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844973/how-to-automate-a-grid-belonging-to-apexgrid-in-testcomplete)
but it is not sufficient. I would like to select the row based on its content instead of its index number.

Please can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some native VB Object properties to be used to get the Cell Text of the selected column and row.

```
sub ClicktheRowUsingText(rowText, rowIndex)
    Dim textfromCell, rowIndex, rowCount, i
    rowCount = tgridNew.ApproxCount
    for i=1 to rowCount-1
        textfromCell = tgridNew.Columns.Item(0).CellText(rowIndex)
            if textFromCell = rowText Then
                'Call here the methods given in the above links
                Exit for
            End if
    Next
End Sub
```